Understanding primary current in half-bridge push-pull converter
I am currently investigating a half-bridge push-pull converter and I am struggling with understanding what I see on the oscilloscope. (And why it keeps blowing up).
So for the circuit, its as basic as it could get, use this for reference (schematic borrowed there):

Of course, add the free wheeling diodes, gate drivers/HVICs etc.
So what I noticed is the following. Consider this oscillogram taken with the circuit running at fairly light load:

Green and purple are high (differential probe) and low side (normal probe) gates, respectively, blue is transformer primary current (inductive current probe) and turquoise is the switching node (i.e., where T1/T2 meet). It's running at 25kHz, link voltage is around 200V. So basically:

high side on
switching node at 200V, so V1 (across the transformer in the schematic) is -100V.
current rises linearly.
high side off
current free-wheels into ground, so switch node goes there, too
low side on
switching node at ground, V1 is +100V
current rises linearly
low side off
current free-wheels into link.

A bit of ringing here and there, nobody's perfect. It has snubber networks around.
Now this happens at higher loads:

So during the on-time of the transistors the primary current actually stops increasing but decreases already. Even worse, where it normally is supposed to free-wheel in the opposite leg of the half bridge, here it doesn't actually want to free-wheel there at all. Instead it seems that, telling from the switch node voltage, it is free-wheeling into the wrong diode: After the high side turns off the switch node goes to ground for a tiny spike and then back to the link voltage again.
So when then turning on the other leg (low side) it might ultimately crash because of the diode recovery (or, MOSFET body diode recovery - depending on how good the dedicated free-wheeling diode behaves). I guess that's what I see on the next screen:

So what on earth am I seeing there (I mean apart from the shoot-through)?
The transformer core should not be saturating - I'm inducing about 300mT and it can take about twice of that for saturation according to the datasheet. Also, if saturated I would have expected a sharp increase in current.
Bear with me, this question is right now more of a "does that ring a bell" kind.
I'll be happy to provide more details, but I'm a bit lost right now...
Update 2024-11-12
I traced out the primary current with a transformer that has the secondary winding open/removed, as of now that's easier than probing the secondary current itself unfortunately.

I kept the vertical deflections the same for easy comparison - it's about 500mApp of magnetization current, which matches very well what I calculated and expected. So I guess Kevin made a good point and I am mostly seeing the reflected secondary current.
Update 2024-11-17
So I did some Spice simulations just to get a notion of what is going on, and I think the reflected secondary current is causing the trouble indeed.
What I found out is that the transformer is rather leaky in construction, having quite a bit of leakage inductance - high voltage output, so it has a rather stretched secondary winding. Also and more importantly the rectifier due to its construction provides a considerable amount of stray capacitance, lowering the overall resonance frequency to a point that resonance becomes observable.
The problem now is that,

I can't greatly increase the switching frequency, as this would also greatly increase the loss through the stray capacitance, and
I can't do much about the stray capacitance in the first place...

Will further investigate.
Update 2024-12-12
So I found out what it all was about.
Basically the output inductor is too small, that's why the current is reversing. While this definitely has to be addressed it doesn't cause much harm at the moment.
What I am actually seeing in the last screenshot, however, is just EMC. It actually is the gate driver IC going bananas due to stray EM. The circuitry around it is fine, the voltage supplies are solid etc.
There is actually a varistor connected to the switching node for protection, and this varistor's capacitance is causing the issue. As soon as I disconnect it the circuit works like a charm, no glitches, no dying transistors...

What centre voltage capacitors are you using? I ask because it looks like you are hitting series resonance. What does the centre/mid voltage look like and, is it hitting an upper or lower rail?

Did you trigger OCP?

Can you display the current in the secondary as well? Some of the primary current will be reflected secondary current that is also changing.

@winny: No OCP so far.

@Andyaka Center voltage travels about 10Vpp around the 100V center voltage. so no worries there I think. I use film caps.

It still looks like resonance to me.

As the latest edit resolves the question, consider posting it as an answer -- but also, consider updating the question so that it includes such necessary information that someone else could arrive such a resolution. (Namely, a representative or original schematic, or layout, was never posted, so no one could possibly guess that there was a varistor to cause problems.)

Seems you have the output coil L with too low inductance shaping the current to sine instead of linear.
What is the output voltage (ratio) and output load? This determines what L is needed.
